# Where is an iOS app's window hierarchy set?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm trying to do something simple, to move from one screen to another. I'm getting error messages relating to the window hierarchy.  `"…whose view is not in the window hierarchy."` I want to know what constitutes the window hierarchy, and how I manage it.

**Update:** my error seems to have been to call presentation code in `viewDidLoad`. I think this means that at the time viewDidLoad is called, the other view either does not exist, or its instance is not yet part of the hierarchy. Moving the same code without modification to an `IBAction` function worked immediately.

I understand perfectly that the way Stackoverflow tends to work is focused on specific coding problems, which was how the initial comment on my question is framed. That's totally reasonable on his part, but I think the point here is that many problems are solved, and solved more broadly, with a conceptual framework provided for how iOS/Swift, but of course any other technology structures itself.

In the comment was the clue that provided the solution to the question, which is when he said that the view "hasn't been presented yet". Allowing for the completion of the entire instantiation of the main view seems to have been the key.

But the question arose because I'm trying to design a curriculum and my task is to figure out how students will get things wrong, and how teachers can frame answers that provide general heuristics for problems of a general type, not in a specific situation.

I know there's room for debate about this, and few people are developing curriculum that come here. But everyone seeking a solution also is developing a conceptual framework around the technology they're learning. So perhaps that can be considered when people generously share their knowledge here – something that I have been a beneficiary of, and appreciate.

Comment: The window hierarchy is established by *your code*; it is the views that your code presents.  If you [edit] your question and show the relevant code we can probably help you. In general the error you have means that you have tried to present a new view on a view that you haven't already presented.

Comment: I'd take it as a given that it's established by code – I can't see what else it would be established by. The question stands, because I'm trying to understand conceptually what constitutes the hierarchy. To be more specific in the general direction I'm currently interested in: Where does the app look to find views that can be segued to? For instance, a main view presenting a modal view (a help screen, or whatever). My focus is on curriculum development, not solving a specfic problem.

Comment: The app doesn't "Look for views that can be segued to".  If you use a storyboard then you can use `performSegue` in code or a segue linked from a button in the storyboard to trigger the segue.  When a segue fires then UIKit takes care of instantiating the view controller and presenting it.  If you allocate a view controller yourself then you can use `present` or `show` to present that view controller; You `show` or `present` from the *current* view controller (which will be in the viewer hierarchy).

Comment: If your view controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController` then that manages a "stack" of view controllers.  Apple's documentation is here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller But there are also lots of iOS programming tutorials that will introduce you to the platform

Comment: @Paulw11, I appreciate the input.